# File io error Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a program that monitors a folder with word documents for any modifications made on the files. The error -Windows Error[2] The system cannot find the file specified- comes when I run the program, open a .doc within the folder make some changes and save it. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Edit1: the actual error code is like this

```
File "C:\Users\keinsfield\Desktop\docu.py", line 27, in check
   if info[0]==os.stat(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\keinsfield\Desktop\colegio",file
).st_ctime:
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\k
insfield\\Desktop\\colegio\\~WRD1761.tmp'
```

Here's the code:

```
def archivar():
    txt = open('archivo.txt', 'r+' )
    for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\keinsfield\Desktop\colegio"):
        for file in files:
            time  = os.stat(os.path.join(rootdir, file)).st_ctime
            txt.write(file +','+str(time) + '\n')
def check():
    txt = [col.split(',') for col in (open('archivo.txt', 'r+').read().split('\n'))]
    files = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\keinsfield\Desktop\colegio")  
    for file in files:
        for info in txt:
                if info[0]==os.stat(os.path.join(r"C:\Users\keinsfield\Desktop\colegio",file)).st_ctime:
                   print "modified"
```

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error. The last two lines are indented the same amount of space. Is this right?

Comment: Is any of the files open in another program while you're running the script?

Comment: the OP mentions "word documents" and ".doc", yet in the code, i only see references to "archivo.txt". also, interestingly enough, the word "archivo" means "file" in spanish, and "colegio" means "high school"... hmmm.

Comment: The program stores all  the files in the folder "Colegio", which are .doc documents. and the corresponding date of modification in "archivo.txt". The program that I am doing is no homework at all, it is suppose to mail me the word documents to my mail because I constanly forget to print them at home.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `os.path.join()` eg

```
root="c:\\"
path=os.path.join(root,"Users","keinsfield","Desktop","colegio")
....
 for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think from the traceback it's quite clear that the *temporary* file was deleted between `os.walk` and `os.stat` calls. You don't really need to use the `os.walk` if you're not recursing into the subdirectories. You could use [`glob.iglob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) to obtain the list of only doc files:

```
for file in glob.iglob(os.path.join(root, '*.doc')):
    print(file)
```

Comment: I did this and still it doesn't work, but thanks for the new info. The only solution I have found for the problem is delaying the check function some time.

Comment: @serpiente: in your `check` function you also need to use `glob.iglob`. you don't need all the files that `os.listdir` returns, but only doc files.